# Ajax responded html got changed during placing on page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, pyrocms

In pyrocms i have a listing view on which i use Jquery Ajax for filtering of records. i have an image attached with each record which i display using lightbox. When page loads at first it works fine, but when i use filtering i got correct html for image and link but when i place that html on view it got change from

```
<a href="http://localhost/pyrocms/upload/2_LBergereChairWU2-1.jpg" class="lightbox cboxElement">
<img src="http://localhost/pyrocms/upload/2_LBergereChairWU2-1.jpg" height="20" width="20">
</a>
```

to this

```
 <a href="http://localhost/pyrocms/upload/2_LBergereChairWU2-1.jpg" class="lightbox cboxElement"></a>
<img src="http://localhost/pyrocms/upload/2_LBergereChairWU2-1.jpg" height="20" width="20">
```

whats the problem with that any help please...

this is my jquery code

```
 $('#nameSearch').click(function(){
var name =$('#name').val();
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"admin/inventory_items/filter",
        data:"name="+name,
        success:function(html){
            $('#itemsfilter').html(html);
        }
    })
    return false;
 });
```

and this is my filter method

```
 public function filter() {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['catagory'])){$cat = $_REQUEST['catagory']; $items = $this->inventory_items_m->getoncat($cat);}
    if(isset($_REQUEST['subcatagory'])){$subcat = $_REQUEST['subcatagory']; $items = $this->inventory_items_m->getonsubcat($subcat);}
    if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])){$name = $_REQUEST['name']; $items = $this->inventory_items_m->getonname($name);}
    $catagories = $this->inventory_catagories_m->get_catagories();
    $subcatagories = $this->inventory_subcatagories_m->get_subcatagories();
    $images = $this->inventory_items_m->getimages();
    foreach ($items->result() as $item) {
        echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>"; echo $item->id; echo "</td>";
                 echo "<td>";
                   //for images
                $img = NULL; $i=0;

                foreach ($images->result() as $image) {

                        if($image->id == $item->id){
                            $img[$i] = $image->filename;
                            $i++;
                            }


                    }
                    $num = count($img);

                if($num>0):
                  for($j=0; $j<1; $j++) { 
                    echo "<a href=\"".site_url()."upload/".$img[($j)]."\" class='lightbox cboxElement' />";
                        echo "<img src=\"".site_url().'upload/'.$img[($j)]."\"  height=\"20\" width=\"20\" />";
                    echo "</a>";
                    }


                endif;
               echo "</td>";
               echo "<td>"; echo $item->name; echo "</td>";
               echo "<td>"; echo $item->desc; echo "</td>";
               echo "<td>"; echo $item->no_of_items; echo "</td>";


                //for name of catagory
                foreach ($catagories as $catagory) {
                        if($catagory->id == $item->catagory) {
                            $catagoryname = $catagory->name;
                        }
                    }


                //<!-- for name of subcatagory -->
                foreach ($subcatagories as $subcatagory) {
                        if($subcatagory->id == $item->subcatagory) {
                            $subcatagoryname = $subcatagory->name;
                        }
                    }




                echo "<td>"; echo @$catagoryname; "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo @$subcatagoryname; "</td>";
                echo "<td class=\"actions\" style=\"width: 325px;\">";
                echo "<div class=\"buttons\">";                
                echo anchor('admin/inventory_items/uploadImages/'.$item->id, lang('button.img'),'class="button edit"')." ";
                echo anchor('admin/inventory_items/addnotes/'.$item->id, lang('button.notes'),'class="button edit"')." ";
                echo anchor('admin/inventory_items/edit/'.$item->id.'/'.$item->catagory.'/'.$item->subcatagory, lang('buttons.edit'), 'class="button edit"')." ";
                echo anchor('admin/inventory_items/delete/'.$item->id, lang('buttons.delete'), 'class="confirm button delete"'); 
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }


}
```

now check please

Comment: what  you doing can you show us your code ?

Comment: wait i am editing my question i will put their my code

Comment: check in filter method the for loop echoing records in proper order and i have checked my response in firebug it is correct i-e img is wrapped in the a tag, but when i place this code usign jquery in the #itemsfilter it get changed img get out of the a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got the answer i have an extra slash in anchor tag

```
echo "<a href=\"".site_url()."upload/".$img[($j)]."\" class='lightbox cboxElement' />";
```

just removing that last slash before ">" sloved my problem 
Anyway thanx Mr NullPointer

Comment: it is always that simple :)